# Can someone explain to me this Chunk Size value

Tags: c#, hex, wav, wave

So I have a wave file containing 110528 bytes, I converted this wave file to hex :

```
byte[] myWaveFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/") + "/Funny.wav");
string myHexFile = ToHex(myWaveFile, 0, myWaveFile.Length);

// myHexFile = "52494646B8AF0100......";
```

The first part of a wave file is the Chunk ID, which is : "52494646" = "RIFF"
but my second part is "B8AF0100" which is basically the chunk size in bytes.

How this value "B8AF0100" can be equal to wave file size ? I converted this value to integer it gives me : 3098476800, nothing to have with 110528 !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [linked page](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)

> The default byte ordering assumed for WAVE data files is little-endian. Files written using the big-endian byte ordering scheme have the identifier RIFX instead of RIFF.

The four bytes making up the chunk size  are `B8`, `AF`, `01` and `00`. As your file has the identifier `RIFF` it is little-endian.  This means the least-significant byte comes first.  The chunk size is therefore not `B8AF0100` in hex, but `0001AFB8`.  This evaluates to 110520, 8 bytes less than the file size.

Comment: Ok I understand now thank you, another last question, my machine is little-endian right, so for the first part of my wave file i got "52494646", i should get "46464952" instead of "52494646". Because in this website : http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/, it says that chunkid = (52494646 in big-endian form)

Comment: @MehdiSouregi: Endian-ness only relates to how you put bytes together to make multi-byte integers.  The chunk size is an integer so you need to know in which order to combine the bytes to make up that integer.  The chunk ID isn't an integer, it's four bytes `R`, `I`, `F` and `F` which must occur in that order.  You should therefore get `52494646` for the first four bytes (which you do), not `46464952`.